# Keep items on same line in a dynamic width sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, animation

I'm trying to create a sidebar for a webpage. Now I want the sidebar to be collapsible with an animation but I cannot find a way of keeping the `<img>` and `<span>` on the same line when collapsing because the width of both tags exceeds the width of the sidebar.

I tried everything than I could think of, played with `float`, `display`, `overflow`, etc.

Here is a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Artyfice/h0ey6bm5/1/) to give you an idea.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  $('#sidebar, #mainContent').toggleClass('expanded');
  $('#sidebar, #mainContent').toggleClass('collapsed');

  if ($("#sidebar").hasClass("collapsed"))
    $("#toggler a").html("&gt;&gt;");
  else
    $("#toggler a").html("&lt;&lt;");
}
```

```css
#mainContent {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #00f;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

ul.nav-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#toggler a {
  float: right;
}

ul.nav-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li,
ul.nav-sidebar li a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ar-icon {
  width: 50px;
}

#sidebar ul li span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar.collapsed ul li span {
  /*display: none;*/
}

#mainContent,
#sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#sidebar,
#mainContent {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainContent.expanded {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

#mainContent.collapsed {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#sidebar.expanded {
  width: 200px;
}

#sidebar.collapsed {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div class="expanded" id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li id="toggler" onclick="toggleSidebar();"><a>&lt;&lt;</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>LongLongLong</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>Short</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (changes commented):

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  $('#sidebar, #mainContent').toggleClass('expanded');
  $('#sidebar, #mainContent').toggleClass('collapsed');

  if ($("#sidebar").hasClass("collapsed"))
    $("#toggler").html("&gt;&gt;"); /* modified */
  else
    $("#toggler").html("&lt;&lt;"); /* modified */
}
```

```css
#mainContent {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

#sidebar {
  overflow: hidden; /* added */
  background-color: #00f;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

ul.nav-sidebar {
  width: 200px; /* modified; needs to match the width of the #sidebar.expanded */
  padding: 0px;
}

#toggler { /* modified */
  /* added */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: right; /* instead of "float: right" */
}

/* addition */
#toggler:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li,
ul.nav-sidebar li a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ar-icon {
  width: 50px;
}

#sidebar ul li span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar.collapsed ul li span {
  /*display: none;*/
}

#mainContent,
#sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#sidebar,
#mainContent {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainContent.expanded {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

#mainContent.collapsed {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#sidebar.expanded {
  width: 200px;
}

#sidebar.collapsed {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div class="expanded" id="sidebar">
    <a id="toggler" onclick="toggleSidebar();">&lt;&lt;</a> <!-- moved outside -->
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li><a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>LongLongLong</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>Short</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
  <!-- a few extra divs, just to see the overflow in action -->
</div>
```

Comment: I thought having `width: 100%;` for the `<ul>` would be enough since its parent width is set. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes but that makes it dynamic in relation to the parents width which, in your case, is not the desired result, so giving it a fixed value is a must. This is a typical confusion. You can also leave the `#toggler` inside the `#nav-sidebar` and use the positioning, but I think the solution is pretty clean. No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do it simply:

```
ul.nav-sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvemao2y/)**

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  $('#sidebar, #mainContent').toggleClass('expanded');
  $('#sidebar, #mainContent').toggleClass('collapsed');

  if ($("#sidebar").hasClass("collapsed"))
    $("#toggler a").html("&gt;&gt;");
  else
    $("#toggler a").html("&lt;&lt;");
}
```

```css
#mainContent {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #00f;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

ul.nav-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#toggler a {
  float: right;
}

ul.nav-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li,
ul.nav-sidebar li a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ar-icon {
  width: 50px;
}

#sidebar ul li span {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar.collapsed ul li span {
  /*display: none;*/
}

#mainContent,
#sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#sidebar,
#mainContent {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainContent.expanded {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

#mainContent.collapsed {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#sidebar.expanded {
  width: 200px;
}

#sidebar.collapsed {
  width: 80px;
}

ul.nav-sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div class="expanded" id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li id="toggler" onclick="toggleSidebar();"><a>&lt;&lt;</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>LongLongLong</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>Short</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a class to the navigation items you want to stay inline and set a min-width to them. I added the class "nav-item", and then set "#sidebar" overflow to hidden;

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="expanded" id="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li id="toggler" onclick="toggleSidebar();"><a>&lt;&lt;</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"> //new class
                <a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>LongLongLong</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> //new class
                <a href="#"><img class="ar-icon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52ffd8dde4b0ee230b35177c/t/53112738e4b060dc36b1db22/1393633080869/Domvision+House+50px.png"><span>Short</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsed" id="mainContent">Dummy content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-item {
    min-width: 250px; /* This can be as big as small as you need */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute sizes for the list elements in order to make it work with `overflow`, else when you collapse the sidebar the list elements change their size automatically as well leading to a break into a new line.

Try this:

```
ul.nav-sidebar li:not(:first-child) {
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

you assign the sidebar a fixed size, so you could do that for the list elements as well leading with `overflow:hidden` to your desired behaviour (if I got it right what you want to accomplish).

Here a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h0ey6bm5/19/

Comment: This hides the menu toggle when closed.

Comment: simple fix for that: 
use `ul.nav-sidebar li:not(:first-child)` as selector